# Create custom password for protected directory on CloudCannon

Tags: jekyll, cloudcannon

Using CloudCannon, you can create [custom routes](https://docs.cloudcannon.com/hosting/authentication/custom-routes/) to password protect a specific directory within your site. Is it possible to create a custom password for the directory? Or do you have to use your CloudCannon login? There's no mention of a password within the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a second site on a subpath (https://cloudcannon.com/jekyll/2019/09/30/exploring-subpaths/), and password-protecting the second site.

Answer (score 0):

When you set up password authentication (https://docs.cloudcannon.com/hosting/authentication/password/), you set a password that website viewers will have to enter before viewing your site (separate from any other sort of log in). By default, this applies to your entire site.

The custom routes you mention let you specify which parts of your site have that authentication applied. Adding one route here would let you password protect one folder and the rest would be public.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use your CloudCannon login. Go to Settings > Authentication > Password to set the password for the custom route.